# Can we recover dynamics from coisotropic reduction?

Tags: differential-geometry, classical-mechanics, symplectic-geometry

I am trying to understand the significance of coisotropic reduction in a mechanical way.

Let $(M,\omega)$ be a symplectic manifold and $i: N \hookrightarrow M$ a coisotropic submanifold i.e. $T_qN^{\perp} \subseteq T_qN \,\,\, \forall q \in N.$ The distribution $TN^\perp$ is regular and involutive and thus comes from a maximal regular foliation $\mathcal{F}$. Suppose $N/\mathcal{F}$, the space of all leaves, has a smooth manifold structure such that $\pi: N \rightarrow N/\mathcal{F}$ (the canonical projection) defines a submersion. Then, the Weinstein Theorem guarantees the existence of an unique symplectic form $\omega_N$ in $N/\mathcal{F}$ such that $\pi^*\omega_N = i^*\omega.$

In the case of reduction arising from symmetries from a Lie group $G$ (an action $\Phi: G \times M \rightarrow M$), an invariant Hamiltonian $H$ projects to a Hamiltonian $\widetilde H$ in the orbit space (that also inherits an unique symplectic structure). In this case, the dynamics of $X_H$ can be completely recovered from the dynamics of $X_{\widetilde H}$.

Is this also true for coisotropic reduction? That is, given a Hamiltonian $H$ (I am guessing that we need to ask $X_H$ to be tangent to $N$ so the dynamics are constrained), does it project to a Hamiltonian $\widetilde H$ in $N/\mathcal{F}$ such that the mechanics from $X_H$ can always be recovered from the mechanics of $X_{\widetilde H}$?

Comment: In general, given a submersion (or merely a surjection) $F: M\to N$, what is the condition on $H: M\to \mathbb{R}$ that guarantees $H$ is the pullback of a function on $N$? If we are to have a Hamiltonian on $M$ yield the mechanics on $N/\mathcal{F}$ it is reasonable to assume that it comes from a Hamiltonian which lifts from $N$ and $N/\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: The condition would just be that $H$ is constant along the fibers right? But this would be the case if $X_H$ is tangent to $N$ since for any $X$ tangent to the distribution $TN^{\perp}$ we have $$\mathcal{L}_X H = dH \cdot X = \omega(X_H, X) = 0$$ and any two points in the same fiber can be joined by a finite union of flows of vector fields tangent to $TN^{\perp}$.

My question is if knowing the flow of $X_{\widetilde H}$ (say $\widetilde H([q]) := H(q)$) gives us a way to recover the flow of $X_H$, at least in $N$. 

Edit: Accidentaly sent message before completion.